# An Elementary Question on Kummer Theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This perhaps may be a rather silly elementary question:

Suppose we have $\zeta_p \in K$,  $K$ and algebraic number field $\zeta_p$ a primative p-th root of unity, $p$-prime

Suppose also we have $L = K( \sqrt[p]{D} )$ where $D \in \mathbb{Z}^{>2}$.

Suppose $\sigma \in Gal(L/K) $ and let $\xi \in L$ such that $\sigma(\xi)/\xi = (\zeta_p)^i$.

Can we conclude from the Kummer theory that if this is so then $\xi = \sqrt[p]{D} \cdot \xi_1$ where $\xi_1 \in K$?

This is just bothering me ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $\zeta_p\in K$ and $D\in K,D^{1/p}\not \in K$ then $x^p-D\in K[x]$ is irreducible, $[K(D^{1/p}):K]=p$, $$K(D^{1/p})=\bigoplus_{n=0}^{p-1} D^{n/p} K \tag{1}$$

Let $\sigma\in Gal(K(D^{1/p})/K),\sigma(D^{n/p})=\zeta_p^n D^{n/p}$ .

$(1)$ is a decomposition as a direct sum of $1$-dimensional eigenspaces of $\sigma$ (seen as an element of $End_K(K(D^{1/p}))$), with distinct eigenvalues.

So $\sigma(a)=\zeta_p^n a$ iff $a\in D^{n/p}K$.

Comment: Yes Yes thank you for that. You've eased my mind. My follow up question is can you claim this fact to be true by direct consequence of the Kummer Theory?